# Magento 2 get custom attribute and show on phtml file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have created a custom product attribute using a module.

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'special_feature',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Special Feature',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 12,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'Special Feature',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            ]
        );
```

The attribute is showing in the product edit page and getting saved. Now, when I try to get the value using `$product->getSpecialFeature()` in the .phtml file, it is not showing anything. I am looping through the product collection generated from the code below in my Block class.

```
public function getProductCollectionByCategories($ids)
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $ids]);
        return $collection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch value of attribute Use:

First get Your Product Collection and then

> $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('attribute_text');

e.g: `$this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('special_feature');`

or please use the productRepositry with get method by product id

Comment: What is $this? Where do I need to call this, in the collection loop?

Comment: Please loop through the product collection and use the productRepositry with get method of product id .

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getAttributeText('special_feature'));     
    echo "<br>";
}
```